# Can't update mySql database

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, I'm new to  mySql. I'm trying to update the database,  and it doesn't work. I've checked the code, and it seems to be correct, but nothing gets updated.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't just say `echo "ERROR"` - that's useless. say something like `echo mysql_error()` instead, which'd give the exact reason the query blew up.

Comment: Two things: 1) checking `$result` will probably always return a positive answer. The return from an `UPDATE` will appear the same to PHP whether it succeeds or not, except for if it crashes in MySQL. 2) check to see if you actually have a record with `id=$id`.  You should do a dump of your variables before this query to see that they are what they need to be.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your database schema, I'm not sure how we can help you. What values are being passed in the `$tbl_name`, `$id`, etc. variables during an unsuccessful update? Have you checked that the data isn't updated in the DB itself, or are you inferring that from `$result`?

Comment: just a guess, but quick to check: id=$id (numerical) or id='$id' (char)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tamara: You're not getting / setting `$name`, `$lastname`, `$email` or `$id`...

Comment: Also, if you were setting them via `$_POST['lastname']` and so forth, try posting `O'Neil` as the surname. Use the PHP manual as often as you can and look up `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I didn't include $id = $_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$email=$_POST['email']; That's why it didn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the id is `INT` (and it should be) you should not use single quotes. That's not for `INT` fields.

Consider the following code:

```
// sets the variables
$id = $_GET['id']; // lets assume you get the id with GET
$name = 'Some Name';
$lastname = 'Some Last Name';
$email = 'email@domain.com';

$sql="UPDATE ".$tbl_name." SET name='".$name."', lastname='".$lastname."', email='".$email."' WHERE id=".$id;
```

Comment: It'll actually still work if it's quoted.  The problem is most likely that there aren't any rows in the database with `id='$id'`, so nothing gets updated and no errors get thrown